# Comparing numbers from a label

Tags: vb.net, numbers

I'm checking if a number is in between to sets of numbers for example. if x is less than or equal to 300 but greater or equal to 60 here is my code

```
Private Sub CheckMode_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckMode.Click
    cn = New ADODB.Connection
    rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    conDB()
    cn.Open()
    rs.Open("Select * From tb_client_mode", cn, 0, 3)
    Dim strClass = GetSessionClass.Text
    Dim strFree = GetSessionFree.Text
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs("st_mode").Value = strClass And TimePerDay.Text = "0" Then
            ClassSession()
            ModeCatchTimer.Stop()
            ModeCatchTimer.Enabled = False
            ModeLabel.Text = "classtime"
            MsgBox("Class Session, Your time will not be deducted", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
            Me.Select()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf rs("st_mode").Value = strFree And TimePerDay.Text = "0" Then
            ModeCatchTimer.Stop()
            ModeCatchTimer.Enabled = False
            cn.BeginTrans()
            cn.Execute("UPDATE tb_registration SET st_log='out' WHERE st_acc_number='" & id_lbl.Text & "'")
            cn.CommitTrans()
            cn.Close()
            Using ClientLockx As New ClientLock
                ClientLock.ShowDialog()
            End Using
            Me.Close()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf rs("st_mode").Value = strClass Then
            ClassSession()
            ModeCatchTimer.Stop()
            ModeCatchTimer.Enabled = False
            ModeLabel.Text = "classtime"
            MsgBox("Class Session, Your time will not be deducted", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
            Me.Select()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf rs("st_mode").Value = strFree And (TimePerDay.Text <= "298") & TimePerDay.Text >= "59" Then
            FreeSessionMinutesLeft()
            ModeCatchTimer.Stop()
            ModeCatchTimer.Enabled = False
            ModeLabels.Text = "freetime"
            MsgBox("Free Session, Your Time will be deducted", vbOKOnly + vbSystemModal, "")
            Me.Select()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf rs("st_mode").Value = strFree And (TimePerDay.Text <= "58") & TimePerDay.Text >= "1" Then
            FreeSessionSecondsLeft()
            ModeCatchTimer.Stop()
            ModeCatchTimer.Enabled = False
            ModeLabel.Text = "freetime"
            MsgBox("Free Session, Your Time will be deducted", vbOKOnly + vbSystemModal, "")
            Me.Select()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            rs.MoveNext()
        End If
    Loop
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

And i get this error 
Conversion from string "true288" to type 'Double' is not valid.
What am i doing wrong. i'm new to vb.net, Please advice

Comment: Where are you converting a string to double at all? I don't see the code where you compare numbers. Apart from that you're wide open for sql-injection. Use sql-parameters.

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my post

Comment: I get the error here "ElseIf rs("st_mode").Value = strFree And (TimePerDay.Text <= "298") & TimePerDay.Text >= "59" Then".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a `String` is not a number. So this is not a good idea:

```
TimePerDay.Text <= "298"
```

This compares lexicographically instead of numerically, so `"9"` is greater than `"10"`.

You need to convert the string to an `Integer` by using `Int32.Parse` or `Int32.TryParse`(to handle invalid input).

```
Dim timePerDay As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(TimePerDay.Text, timePerDay) AndAlso timePerDay <= 298 Then
    ' ... '
Else
    MesageBox.Show("Invalid number")
End If
```

Apart from that you're open for [sql-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use sql-parameters instead. Do you need to use [ADO instead of ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y0bb1zd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: ah. so the number values i get from my database are strings?. Now i know, I've searched sql-parameters and I'm gonna implement them soon. are systems and websites open for sql-injection? i thought sql-injections are only applicable on websites. i'll research more about that. thanks for the you spared to answer my question. i'm new at programming and vb.net is my main.

Comment: @LeoElvinLee: `TimePerDay.Text` is a `string` which has to be parsed to `Int32` first. SQL-Injection is possible if you access a database without using sql-parameters but string-concatenation(like `...WHERE st_acc_number='" & id_lbl.Text & "'"`). Websites are just more important since they are mostly accessed via internet.

Comment: I see, after i complete my project, its a computer management system using wampserver as connection and database, since i don't know how to use winsockets, I'll revise everything and set using sql-parameters so i can practice and get used to it. Again I learned something today. Thank you :).